# Add values in list from other API method

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have one list and in that list I am adding values based on class. See below for details.

```
result.ContactList = contactsResult.Item2.Select(x => new PrjContact() { 
                            Id = x.ID, 
                            UserId = x.UserId,
                            Name = xName,
                            Email = x.Email, 
                        }).ToList();
```

Now I need to call one more API and pass this UserId in that API and get phone number for that user.

Then need to add that phone number in above list in result.ContactList.

I have tried in this way.

```
foreach (var user in contactsResult.Item2)
{
   UserInfo = API.GetUserDetail(user.UserId);
   result.ContactList.Select(x => new ProjectContactView()
                            {
                                Phone = UserInfo.PhoneNumber
                            });
}
```

But this is not working.

Comment: What have you tried and what isn't working?  What's stopping you from performing the task you are trying to describe?

Comment: @David I have edited question and added what I have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't do anything:

```
result.ContactList.Select(x => new ProjectContactView()
{
    Phone = UserInfo.PhoneNumber
});
```

Sure, it iterates over `result.ContactList` and projects it into a new collection.  But (1) you don't do anything with that collection and (2) it overwrites every object in that collection with an entirely new object that has only one property set.

For starters, if you want to modify `result.ContactList` then iterate over that:

```
foreach (var user in result.ContactList)
{

}
```

Then if the goal here is to use a property on `user` to fetch data and update `user` then just update `user`:

```
foreach (var user in result.ContactList)
{
    var userInfo = API.GetUserDetail(user.UserId);
    user.Phone = userInfo.PhoneNumber
}
```